# Controllers & Filter are initialized but not getting called

Tags: java, servlets, spring-boot

I'm running very simple Spring Boot application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

I have a simple filter:

```
@Component
public class MyFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException     {
       // This is getting called ! 
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // some logic
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

I'm having a single controller that return an index page:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }

}
```

When requesting the index page, my filter is not getting called although I think it should.

In my logs I see:

```
2016-07-18 11:59:51.840  INFO 15623 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'MyFilter' to: [/*]
```

What am I missing?

After the comments here I saw that my controller is not getting called as well. So this is not a problem with the filter, but this is a symptom to a bigger problem.

This is my project structure:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── build.gradle
├── gradlew
├── settings.gradle
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   └── com
│   │   │       └── mypackage
│   │   │           ├── Application.java
│   │   │           ├── GreetingController.java
│   │   │           ├── HomeController.java
│   │   │           └── MyFilter.java
│   │   └── resources
│   │       ├── application.yml
│   │       └── templates
│   │           ├── greeting.html
│   │           └── index.html
```

I'm building a jar file with `gradle`:

`./gradlew clean build`

And running it:

`java -jar build/libs/sample-webapp-1.0.0.jar`

I'm calling `http://localhost:8080` and getting the `index.html` file (probably not going through the controller).

Spring version is `1.3.6-RELEASE`.

Part of my `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "http://jcenter.bintray.com"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.6.RELEASE")
    }
}

dependencies {
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
        compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.6.2'
        compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.6.2'
        compile group: 'org.bouncycastle', name: 'bcprov-jdk16', version: '1.46'
        testCompile("junit:junit")
}
```

Comment: And how do you test it isn't being called? The filter doesn't do anything, nor contains any logging.

Comment: Logic was deleted to make the question short. I'm debugging with intellij and I have a breakpoint both in the init and the doFiilter function. The first is called and the second is not.

Comment: Is your controller actually called? Are you deploying the application or running the embedded container?

Comment: @M.Deinum I'm running my Application class from intellij and it is starting the tomcat embedded container.

Comment: And you haven't answered the first question, is your controller actually being called.

Comment: Now that you mention it - no it is not. How is that possible? I can see the web page.

Comment: What is the URL you are calling? Also are you building a war or a jar and can you add your project structure to your question.

Comment: Could you also specify which Spring Boot version and templating technology you are using?

Comment: To anyone reading this question and thinking of copying code: don't.
Depending on the use case you would need a service and maybe an entity mapper to handle the request data instead of a Filter.
But if the use case of such a filter is for security reasons then use Spring Boot Security and the SecurityFilterChain.

Answer (score 0):

Your filter map `/*` so your call to index should be http://localhost:8080/index.
How do you call index?

Comment: My index is mapped to /

Answer (score 0):

i guess is tomcat's DefaultServlet take it,you can try add a breakpoint at `org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory#addDefaultServlet`,and then add a breakpoint at `org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet#doGet`.

Answer (score 0):

All classes (including controllers and filters) should be in packages which are one level below the package containing your Application.class file.

Answer (score 0):

@Order(1000) -> Will do the Job For you

```
@Component
@Slf4j
@Order(1000)
public class `Class` implement Filter { } `enter code here`
```